# XLS Stylesheet returns empty Excel sheet

Tags: xml, xslt

Update: Thank you for the answer! Two quick followup questions: I want to be able to see  and  for each item. The code I wrote

```
<xsl:for-each select="item/totalCharges"> 
    <checkouts><xsl:value-of select="totalCharges"/>
</checkouts> </xsl:for-each>
```

isn't working. Is there an easy way to do this? Second, how can I update  to specifically get ?

I apologize in advance if this is a very low level question, but I am not a programmer at all and have reached the end of my ability to troubleshoot this problem. I am trying to use the following XLS stylesheet

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <record>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog">
        <itemline>
            <title><xsl:value-of select="marc/marcEntry"/></title>
            <callNumber><xsl:value-of select="call/callNumber"/></callNumber>
            <yearOfPublication><xsl:value-of select="catalog/yearOfPublication"/></yearOfPublication>
            <xsl:for-each select="item/totalCharges">
                <xsl:value-of select="totalCharges"/>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </itemline>
    </xsl:for-each>     
    </record>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

on an XML report from my library's system. Here is an example of the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sirsi.xsl"?>
<report>
<title>List of Items with Specified Entries</title>
<dateCreated>2017-03-03T12:00:21</dateCreated>
<dateFormat>mm/dd/yyyy</dateFormat>
    <catalog>
    <flexibleKey>111802</flexibleKey>
    <numberOfTitleHolds>0</numberOfTitleHolds>
    <totalHolds>0</totalHolds>
    <numberOfCallNumbers>1</numberOfCallNumbers>
    <bibliographicLevel>FULL</bibliographicLevel>
    <catalogFormat>MARC</catalogFormat>
    <createdBy>BATCH</createdBy>
    <dateCreated>2000-02-17</dateCreated>
    <dateCataloged></dateCataloged>
    <modifiedBy>BATCH</modifiedBy>
    <dateModified>2009-01-08</dateModified>
    <catalogKey>95465</catalogKey>
        <marc>
        <marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">Si rosa yan si ana</marcEntry>
        </marc>
        <call>
        <callNumber>XX(95465.1)</callNumber>
        <library>UOG-RFK</library>
            <item>
            <numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
            <numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
            <numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
            <totalCharges>5</totalCharges>
            <inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
            <totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
            <totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
            <intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
            <intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
            <intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
            <recirculate>YES</recirculate>
            <dateLastUsed>2000-04-20</dateLastUsed>
            <isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
            <copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
            <itemID>33296001077192</itemID>
            <library>UOG-RFK</library>
            <libraryDescription>University of Guam - RFK Memorial Library</libraryDescription>
            <location>JUVENILE</location>
            <homeLocation>JUVENILE</homeLocation>
            <price currency="$" >0.00</price>
            <type>JUVENILE</type>
            <numberOfPieces>1</numberOfPieces>
            <dateCreated>2000-02-17</dateCreated>
            <isPermanent>true</isPermanent>
            </item>
        </call>
</catalog>

<catalog>
<flexibleKey>o21002169</flexibleKey>
<numberOfTitleHolds>0</numberOfTitleHolds>
<totalHolds>0</totalHolds>
<numberOfCallNumbers>1</numberOfCallNumbers>
<bibliographicLevel>FULL</bibliographicLevel>
<catalogFormat>MARC</catalogFormat>
<createdBy>TECH</createdBy>
<dateCreated>2010-07-20</dateCreated>
<dateCataloged>2010-07-20</dateCataloged>
<modifiedBy>SYSADMIN</modifiedBy>
<dateModified>2010-07-21</dateModified>
<catalogKey>138981</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>1984</yearOfPublication>
    <marc>
    <marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Treviño, Elizabeth Borton de, 1904-</marcEntry>
    <marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">I, Juan de Pareja / Elizabeth Borton de Treviño.</marcEntry>
    <marcEntry tag="250" label="Edition" ind="  ">Sunburst ed.</marcEntry>
    <marcEntry tag="260" label="Publication info" ind="  ">New York, NY : Farrar, Straus &amp; Giroux, 1984 (1991 printing)</marcEntry>
    <marcEntry tag="300" label="Physical description" ind="  ">xii, 180 p ; 21 cm.</marcEntry>
    <marcEntry tag="500" label="General Note" ind="  ">&quot;A Sunburst book.&quot;</marcEntry>
    <marcEntry tag="500" label="General Note" ind="  ">&quot;A Newbery Medal book&quot;--Cover.</marcEntry>
    <marcEntry tag="520" label="Summary" ind="  ">Offers a fictionalized account of the life of Juan de Pareja, a young slave who grew to become an assistant to the painter Velasquez.</marcEntry>
    <marcEntry tag="600" label="Personal subject" ind="11">Pareja, Juan de, 1606-1670--Fiction.</marcEntry>
    <marcEntry tag="600" label="Personal subject" ind="11">Velʹazquez, Diego, 1599-1660--Fiction.</marcEntry>
    <marcEntry tag="600" label="Personal subject" ind="10">Pareja, Juan de, 1606-1670--Juvenile fiction.</marcEntry>
    <marcEntry tag="600" label="Personal subject" ind="10">Velázquez, Diego, 1599-1660--Juvenile fiction.</marcEntry>
    <marcEntry tag="650" label="Subject term" ind=" 1">Artists--Spain--Fiction.</marcEntry>
    </marc>
    <call>
    <callNumber>PZ 7.T732 I 1984</callNumber>
    <library>UOG-RFK</library>
        <item>
        <numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
        <numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
        <numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
        <totalCharges>0</totalCharges>
        <inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
        <totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
        <totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
        <intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
        <intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
        <intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
        <recirculate>YES</recirculate>
        <dateLastUsed></dateLastUsed>
        <isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
        <copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
        <itemID>33296001438444</itemID>
        <library>UOG-RFK</library>
        <libraryDescription>University of Guam - RFK Memorial Library</libraryDescription>
        <location>JUVENILE</location>
        <homeLocation>JUVENILE</homeLocation>
        <price currency="$" >25.00</price>
        <category1>JUVENILE</category1>
        <type>JUVENILE</type>
        <numberOfPieces>1</numberOfPieces>
        <dateCreated>2010-07-20</dateCreated>
        <isPermanent>true</isPermanent>
        </item>
    </call>
```

I'm just trying to get one line for each item that has the title, call number, date of publication, and number of checkouts. However, when I open the XML report with my stylesheet it returns an empty workbook. Again, I apologize if I'm missing something easy, but I haven't done any coding in nearly 15 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//catalog">
```

instead of

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog">
```

For your attached question in comment you can use this xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
                <record>
                        <xsl:for-each select="//catalog">
                                <itemline>
                                        <title><xsl:value-of select="marc/marcEntry[@label='Title']"/></title>
                                        <callNumber><xsl:value-of select="call/callNumber"/></callNumber>
                                        <yearOfPublication><xsl:value-of select="yearOfPublication"/></yearOfPublication>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="call/item/totalCharges">
                                                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                                        </xsl:for-each> 
                                </itemline>
                        </xsl:for-each>     
                </record>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It worked! You are amazing. Two quick followup questions: I want to be able to see <numberOfCharges> and <dateLastUsed> for each item. The code I wrote <xsl:for-each select="item/totalCharges"> <checkouts><xsl:value-of select="totalCharges"/></checkouts> </xsl:for-each> isn't working. Is there an easy way to do this? Second, how can I update <title> to specifically get <marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">? Again, thank you so much for your help. I can't begin to explain how much this was driving me nuts.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works perfectly and I understand the language much better now. I don't know if it matters to you, but with your help we are going to be able to actually make a difference in a small University that serves students from some very economically disadvantaged Pacific Islands. Thank you for helping us help our students.